# How can I find the File name after compile the document?

Tags: beamer

I found a part of the sample poster.  When I apply he asked me: “Enter file name?” can you tell me where can I find the file name?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4paper,landscape,dvipsnames]{umbcposter}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mytitle}{
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \LARGE\sc This is the title \\[0.6ex]
    \Large\sl Rouben Rostamian\\
    \Large UMBC
\end{tabular}
}
\posterinit{
%grid,
background style = {left color = Apricot, right color = white},
title = {\mytitle},
right logo,       
left logo,        
box/border style, 
box/header style, 
box/body style = {bottom color=blue!10, top color=red!5},
box/all rounded,
}
\boxit{col = 0, at top, name=box1}{Title of Box 1}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item col = 0
    \item at top
    \item name = box1
\end{itemize}
}
\boxit{col = 0, below of=box1, name=box2}{Title of Box 2}{
\begin{itemize}
    \item col = 0
    \item below of = box1
    \item name = box2
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used  the file name after I saved but it does not accepted

Comment: When you compile a document called `file.tex`  with `pdflatex` you get a PDF file called `file.pdf`. However, I don't really understand what you mean by this. What do you mean by apply? Where do you get the question for the file name?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In particular, we have no idea where you got the sample poster or anything else. Googling [latex "enter file name"](https://www.google.com/search?q=latex+%22enter+file+name%22) indicates you may not have the files in a single folder. But that's a wild guess given the information provided.

Comment: Guessing it is related to [UMBC Poster](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rostamia/umbcposter/), including a tutorial and download links.

Comment: Are umbcposter.cls and other associated files all in the same folder as your own .tex file? If not, that's the cause of your error.